# "as" equivalent using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

So I started with no knowledge on reflection or dynamic typing, but I've learned a lot.  However, there is one thing I cannot find: the "as" equivalent for dynamic typing.

What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of this (if it would compile):

```
foreach (Change c in changes)
{
    (c.Undo as Action<c._Type, c._Type>).Invoke(
        c.OldValue as c._Type, c.NewValue as c._Type);
}
```

From what I understand, I need to do something along the lines of

```
Type constructedClass = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(c._Type);
```

to construct the needed Action class, but is there a way to implement `as` for both the Action type and c._Type?

For further clarification, here is the pseudocode (and this is my first time trying to do this kind of thing, so please be nice):

```
foreach (Object o in objects)
{
    (o.SettableMethod as Action<o.TypeOfParameters, o.TypeOfParameters>).Invoke(
        o.Parameter1 as TypeOfParameters, o.Parameter2 as TypeOfParameters);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's unclear what you want could you give a usage example

Comment: The reason is a little complicated, but I'm storing c.Undo (which should be an Action<T, T>) as an object, as well as its OldValue and NewValue.  I'm trying to assign their proper Types.  There's a bunch of other code, and I don't know which would be useful....

Comment: Just post a sample in pseudo code of what your are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the generics on the Action (or in general) is to allow you to manage type safety at compile time.  If you use reflection, you are doing extra work to *not* get that benefit.  You might as well have the signature of your Undo Action take two objects of type `object`, and cast to appropriate types inside the action, if needed.

Even more generally, you would be better served by a different design.  Why are you calling a method on `Change` that sends properties of `Change` back in?  Could you not call Undo without any parameters, and leave `Change` responsible for knowing what the new and old values are?

Comment: A different design might be beneficial, but this is the only way I can think to do it.  What I'm trying to do is set up a set of classes that can handle undo's and redo's without having to making a huge array of classes for each possible type.  Of course, different types would make you think generics, but I'm having problems with contravariance and trying to get around it.  c.Undo is a method that I give c as a parameter to define how it should undo each Change.  It has no definition; I give it a definition when I make the Change object.

Comment: You can still have it's signature take two objects.  That's how these sort of methods used to all be before generics; generics were added to make type safety easier.  You aren't getting type safety this way.

Comment: Does the undo have to do something besides replace newVal with oldVal?  Another design would be to make it do that.  This means having your Undo work against a Memento object that holds all the interesting state information you want to change.

Comment: Yes, other changes have to be made when I undo, such as changing the UI and making changes to hierarchies.

Comment: And Action<object, object> won't work because c.Undo was already assigned as Action<DifferentType, DifferentType>.